# ios- Get unique identifier which should have to be same after reinstalling of the app

Tags: ios

I have a use case that I want to bind the user with a particular device id. So that purpose I need a unique device identifier.

When I search for this issue I found some solutions like

- Creating an UUID but it gets changed each time when I uninstall the
  app and reinstall.
- Creating a UUID  **Storing id in User Defaults or KeyChain** but latest version of iOS **removes KeyChain and UserDefaults on uninstall** of the app.
- Getting a mac id is also deprecated they always return one mock value 
  **MAC address  02:00:00:00:00:00**.

So my question is it possible to read any unique identifier?
If yes then how can I read it either with swift or objective-c?

Answer (score 1):

At least iOS 12.1 doesn't remove Keychain on app's uninstall.

This removing behavior is once introduced in iOS10.3 Beta 2, but reverted later.

---

In some case DeviceCheck APIs, Apple officially offers, can be solution.

This seems most reliable and decent way, if it meets your requirement.

c.f. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck

> Using the DeviceCheck APIs, in combination with server-to-server APIs, you can set and query two bits of data per device, while maintaining user privacy. You might use this data to identify devices that have already taken advantage of a promotional offer that you provide, or to flag a device that you've determined to be fraudulent. The DeviceCheck APIs also let you verify that the token you receive comes from an authentic Apple device on which your app has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer a way to uniquely identify a device after the user uninstalled the app(s). The documentation says:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: please check this. https://codeburst.io/unique-identifier-for-the-ios-devices-590bb778290d

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is take UUID as well as use case whatever you bind with user then after if user register at that time store your use case as well as UUID and also create unique userId for that.If user is logged out and login again you can check userID and with unique parameter like userEmail or contact which already exists to not?If exist then replace your use case with new(if use case you used each time).

I hope it will help you.
Thanks